# Window onload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using below script which is pulling my page to center on load. Because this script triggers in the center of the page. And once page is loaded it go back to top.

I want the page should start from top when it gets loaded.

```
<script>
j$(document).ready(function() {
j$('div.purple-right ul.icons li #lnkAddCal').on('click', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    j$("div.when ul.icons li #lnkAddCal").click();
    j$('div.when ul.icons li #tdCal').clone().appendTo('div.purple-right ul.icons li');
});
});
j$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      j$('div.purple-right ul.icons li #lnkAddCal').trigger('click');
    },10);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Satpal, but the issue is still there.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     Your_Center_Function(function()
     {
          $("body").scrollTop( 0 );
     });

});
function Your_Center_Function(callback)
{
     // Your center Code

     if(callback)
         callback();
}
```

Comment: Can you please make it a bit easier to understand this snippet?